# How to get html data with json api?

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping

I am webscraping profile pages on khanacademy. I use their API (json file format) to do it.

Here is the profile link I would like to scrape: `https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/Viruslala/`

Here is its API link:
`https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_896965538702696832878421/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190427-0731-8941ef3f07bd_1556382106890`

My problem: most of the data is showing on the json file (API). But some specific data that I would like to scrape is not showing up.

I tried to search for a different API link but I didn't found the right one.

On the first image you have two kind of data I would like to scrape: Blue one and Yellow one.

[image]

On the json file : Blue is showing up. But not Yellow.

[image]

My questions are: 
Why yellow is not showing up? 
How can I get yellow with their API?

Answer (score 1):

Yellow (profile info) can be regex'd out of original url response text.

Explore [json](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=359dbbf831794b74b3b4f4abe23a6de7) here. The pattern `r` leads to extraction of string which can be loaded with `json` to produce dict containing all the info.

```
import requests
import json
import re

res = requests.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/Viruslala/')
r = re.compile(r'profileInitOptions":(.*),"view"', re.DOTALL)
data = json.loads(r.findall(res.text)[0])
profile_data = data['profileData']
print(profile_data)
```

---

Notes:

The page loads the required content dynamically from a `script` tag when javascript runs on the page. As js does not run with requests you can still apply a regex pattern which grabs the javascript object housing the data of interest. You specify the pattern with:

```
r = re.compile(r'profileInitOptions":(.*),"view"', re.DOTALL)
```

then apply it to the response text, `res.text`, and extract the first returned match:

```
r.findall(res.text)[0]
```

In the case of this page, what is returned can be parsed with a json library:

```
json.loads(r.findall(res.text)[0])
```

The string is now in an dictionary object called `data` which you can access info from by key

```
data['profileData']
```

---

Regex:

[image]

---

[re.DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html)

Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline. Corresponds to the inline flag (?s).

Comment: Here you are using ```https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/Viruslala/``` and you get the link with ```requests.get```. The thing is that I would like to avoid using this link because it is taking more time to requests than the API link. I am going to scrape thousands of profiles. Do you have an other solution?

Comment: Does it take much more time than the API? And that is the only place I found the data i'm afraid.

Comment: When I will scale the script, yes it can take quite a lot of time (because there is a lot of images and other useless data with `https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/Viruslala/`). Wich is why I try to use as much as possible their API. Do you know why the data is not showing up on the API?

Comment: Is there API documentation? I assume either wrong endpoint or not provided

Comment: How can I find the API documentation? Also, if I want to run your script but with an other profile that doesn't display the desired data (`https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/zoecod/`). The output is `None 0
0` (see with edits). Do you have an idea on how to get the disered data anyway?

Comment: Also, could you please add some comments to explain your code, I am not sure I understand what you are doing. (especially: `re.compile(r'profileInitOptions":(.*),"view"', re.DOTALL)` and `json.loads(r.findall(res.text)[0])`)

Comment: Sorry, I never saw your last comments! I have updated for you.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to scrape the API? Urllib usually gets what you need

```
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_896965538702696832878421/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190427-0731-8941ef3f07bd_1556382106890") as url:
data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

From the API link it doesn't seem to contain any data for the userSummary, so there's nothing to scrape

Comment: I use requests: ```requests.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_896965538702696832878421/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959'.format(kaid)).json()```

Comment: Indeed there is nothing and that's what I would like ton understand. Why?